# How to create a dynamic Geofence with android

Tags: java, android, android-geofence

I'm learning how to use a `Geofence` with android and my question is : If I have a list of places (lat and long) with a realtime database, I would have to create a new object of `Geofence` everytime that something new is listed? Like this :

```
Geofence geofence = new Geofence.Builder()
.setRequestId(GEOFENCE_REQ_ID) // Geofence ID
.setCircularRegion( LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, RADIUS) // defining fence region
.setExpirationDuration( DURANTION ) // expiring date
// Transition types that it should look for
.setTransitionTypes( Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT )
.build();
```

Here `setCircularRegion( LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, RADIUS)` would be pass the locations ? And how to dandle which one was ? https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Comment: you can use GEOFENCE_REQ_ID to identify.

Comment: but, what about the locations ?

Comment: Read the documentation carefully, `Create geofence objects` tells you how to add multiple geofences.
In your code, You are creating single geofence object. After adding multiple geofence you can find the id (used in `setRequestId `) in your IntentService

Comment: Just so you know there is a limit of 100 geofences per app per user on a device.